# Actionbar background is gone

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I hava set action bar background

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.top_bar_bg));
```

when I went to another activity and come back to original

I lost the background only ,title and icon are remaining as it is

Answer (score 0):

whatever u try in current activity to achieve this in oncreate so just write that code also in onresume() method try this i think it will solve like

@

```
Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
       //here u write your code to achive i think this is your code 
       //getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.top_bar_bg));
}
```